# How to load files from multiple sub-directories simultaneously (jupyter)?

Tags: python, loops, jupyter, wav, librosa

We are data science students. We want to apply several features all the .wav files that we have in 10 different sub-directories.

We can loop successfully on one sub-directory, using this code:

```
zcr = []

for f in sorted(os.listdir('/content/Data/genres_original/blues/')):
    if f.endswith('.wav'):
        # Load file and compute the requested features
        x, signal = librosa.load('/content/Data/genres_original/blues/' + f)
        zcr_ = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(x)
        zcr.append(zcr_)
```

But we failed to do this simultaneously in all the sub-directories.

How can we loop for all sub-directories at the same time?

Our folder structure:

```
 - Root folder

   - Folder 1
     - file 1
     - file 2
     - etc

   - Folder 2
     - file 1
     - file 2
     - etc

   - Folder 3
     - file 1
     - file 2
     - etc

   - Folder n
     - file 1
     - file 2
     - etc
```

Comment: How many ```.wav``` files do you have in total? If the number is not to high (100k - inf :D ). If you have a really huge count of file parallel is a way to go otherwise you should do it sequential.

Comment: Why do you need to do all of the folders at the same time? What difference does it make?

Comment: We have 100 wav files for each sub-directories (total 1k wav files)

Comment: We would like to avoid redundancies within the code @martineau

Comment: In that case put your code in a function that's passed the root directory as an argument and call it 10 times — doing it parallel is a needless complication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native os.walk() method to iterate recursively trough your directories: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

You'll get something like:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_root_directory):
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] != '.wav':
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(root, f)
        # do your stuff
```

An alternative I also recommend to you is the path.py library, which is really convenient when interacting with files: https://path.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html